# How to convert UTC time to configured timezone in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I received a time string from a server and I want to parse or convert that string to configured time zone (Tokyo timezone in my case):

- ```
  Input: "2016-05-27T09:00:00.0000000"
  ```
- ```
  Expected output: Fri, 27 May 2016 18:00:00 JST +09:00
  ```

I try to type like this:

```
Time.zone.parse("2016-05-27T09:00:00.0000000")
```

but it returns unexpected output:

```
Fri, 27 May 2016 09:00:00 JST +09:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parsed datetime is a UTC time, **add the UTC timezone explicitly** to it before parsing:

```
# this parses the time as local time:    
Time.zone.parse("2016-05-27T09:00:00.0000000")
# => Fri, 27 May 2016 09:00:00 JST +09:00

# this parses the time as UTC and converts to local time:    
Time.zone.parse("2016-05-27T09:00:00.0000000Z")
# => Fri, 27 May 2016 18:00:00 JST +09:00
```

Note the "Z" appended to the datetime string, meaning that this is a datetime in UTC timezone.